# Plotting the output using python Matplotlib in Sconstruct

Tags: scons

I have a SConstruct file which compiles a C code and generates some binary files. Currently I am manually running the python script which generates the plot after the SConstruct file. I want to run the executable file and plot the output automatically every time I run the SConstruct. Does any one have any idea how it could be done ?
Here is the sample code.The C code requires an input which is generated by model.py and finally SConstruct generates main.exe (C executable file). main.exe generates another binary files which need to be plotted .Currently I am running a separate python script 'output.py' which generates plot. Also I want model.py to run only when I made some changes in it.The sequence is model.py -> main.c -> output.py (plots) . How can I incorporate this into a single Scons ?

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

execfile('model.py')

env = Environment(ENV = os.environ,CC='gcc')
env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-fopenmp'])
env.Prepend(LIBS=['m'])
ldflags='-fopenmp'

env.Program('main.exe','main.c',LINKFLAGS=ldflags)
```

Comment: Please clarify whether the python script (model.py?) should be run always, or only when the C code or one of the input files to `main.exe` changes. In the former case (run always) you probably don't want SCons but a simple script to do the job instead. It's also not clear to me how your dependencies look like. You say you want to execute "the script" after `main.exe` was created, but also state that the C code requires input from `model.py`...so it has to be run before, doesn't it? Please edit your question to make your intentions clearer.

Comment: so: scons, main.exe. run python script to generate plot? is that the sequence?  Perhaps include your sequence of command lines in your question to clarify.